# ios How To Segue From Single View To Split View Controller

Tags: ios, ios7, segue

I have two template Views (one is a single view and the other is a Split View Controller) each individually works fine. So I put a button on the Single View and put a Push Segue on the button to go to the Split View Controller. When I press the button I get a crash saying Push cant be used from outside UI Navigation Contoller.

Ok so I put the single view template into a UI Navigation Controller and it now says: Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller.

So ... how do I do this ??

Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

Use a container view in a normal View Controller, covering up the whole viewing area, and that container view has an embed segue to the Split View Controller

Overwrite the UISplitViewController and put this in the viewDidLoad if you need to communicate between them:

```
YourLeftVC *masterViewController = (YourLeftVC *) [[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] topViewController];
YourRightVC *detailViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
```

Comment: Interesting idea, - just tried to implement it in test project. Seems like it works!

Comment: if you can please help me a bit more! :(

Answer (score 6):

Instead of presenting splitviewcontroller try to set as rootviewcontroller.

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
```

Comment: Would you use an animation to make it look like a modal segue?

Answer (score 1):

As per apples documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html

A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create.
you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window.

What you can do here is create a custom splitview.

Comment: Those docs are out of date. In UISplitViewController's docs: "You cannot push a split view controller onto a navigation stack. Although it is possible to install a split view controller as a child in some other container view controllers, doing is not recommended in most cases. Split view controllers are normally installed at the root of your app’s window. For tips and guidance about ways to implement your interface, see iOS Human Interface Guidelines."

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario you could create a second UIViewController to make the push, and on it a container that have the UISplitViewController as root.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: The navigation would be a UIViewController that pushes to another UIViewController, but on the second you need to fill it with a UIContainerView.
The UIContainerView then needs to have a UISplitViewController embed.
I'll put a image to clear the picture, and I say it's a worst case scenario because this solution is not that straightforward... 
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/6bwmkpbf0costom/SplitViewController%20on%20Navigation.png)

Answer (score -2):

Set your segue to modal and not push, that should do it.

**EDIT**

Actually that doesn't work. What you can try is putting your splitView in another storyboard, and in your buttonClicked: method present it in code :

In SigleView.m :

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:
{
    SplitViewController *splitVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SplitStoryBoard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewController];
    [self presentViewController:splitVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT2**

What's written before isn't working either. I really wonder if you CAN present a splitViewController (i.e not make it your rootViewController).

But there's someting you can do :

Set your splitView as the rootView of your app, present modally your singleView at launch, and whenever you want just dismiss it to let the splitView have control. Will have the same effect than having your singleView presenting the splitView.

Comment: No none of this works. For some reason IOS does not like going from single view UI controller to SplitView.

Comment: It says the error is "Application tried to present Split View Controller modally"

Comment: This generates a "Application tried to present a Split View Controller modally" error

Comment: Edited again, you can set the splitView as rootView and present/dismiss the singleView over it

Comment: @shinyuX, how did you get the controller to present on the initial view?

Comment: In the viewDidLayoutSubviews (or viewDidLoad) of the splitViewController, add a `[self presentViewController:mySingleViewController animated:YES completion:nil]`