# segue from UITableViewController to UISplitViewController Swift - Iphone App

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have implemented a `SWRevealViewController` menu having as a rear view a `UITableViewController` with few labels on it. What I want to do is to segue from these label to a `UISplitViewController`. 
When I ctrl click and drag from a label to UISplitViewController, no segue option shows. Here is a screenshot of Main.storyboard

[image]

Also there is no way I can embed the UISplitViewController in a UINavigationController, when I go to Editor/Embed in, all options are greyed.

Comment: You already got it - you can't do segues without a navigation controller.

Comment: @brandonscript      I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact do this with a UINavigation controller in combination with a container view and a second view controller.

1. Add a UINavigationController to your storyboard and ensure it's set as the initial view controller:

   [image]
2. Delete the unnecessary table view controller that Xcode automatically added
3. Add a UIViewController to your storyboard (let's rename it `VC1`)
4. From the storyboard navigation tree, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag from the navigation controller to VC1 and select `root view controller` under Relationship Segue from the popup:
   [image]
5. Add a UIButton to VC1:

   [image]
6. Add a second view controller to the scene (let's rename it `VC2`)
7. Add a Container View to VC2, *replacing* the initial view (drag it over top of the view so it highlights gray):

   [image]

   If you did it right, it should look like this:

   [image]
8. Delete the unnecessary View Controller that Xcode automatically added to the scene and embedded in the container view, then add a Split View Controller to the scene in its place
9. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag from VC2's container view to the Split View Controller and select Embed:
   [image]
10. Last but not least, add a show (prev. push) segue from the button in VC1 to VC2 -- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag from the button in VC1 to the VC2 controller and select Show:

    [image]

Comment: . I have added a UIViewController to my storyboard, embedded it in a UINavigationController, then set the new viewcontroller as the root viewcontroller in App Delegate file using this code snippet : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a72eee48d519dd09ad0d3592663d4df5   . Then I added the UISplitViewController and dragged to it a Show segue from the button. I don't know how to  add a navigation component to push the split VC onto the stack. Is this code placed in App delegate?

Comment: All of what I did ^ is completely done in IB - no code. The button is just the segue trigger. You _could_ replicate this in code, but why would you want to? It takes about 30 seconds to wire up what I've done here -- and half of that is waiting for Xcode to render the elements.

Comment: OH snap. You're right. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24774345/1214800. You'll need to use a container view controller as well.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Could you build a Xcode project with as per your instructions above and upload it. Thanks

Comment: OK, that took way longer than I'd expected, but see update. Best to see if you can get it working from the instructions so that future people can learn from it (and so I don't have to permanently host the Xcode project).

Comment: @ brandonscript I have followed the exact steps, but I get this warning in the console 'Test2[3521:7343131] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <Test2.DetailViewController: 0x7f9a0341ba80>.' When I click on the button, it takes me straight to the detailViewController rather than to the RootViewController.

Comment: Yeah best I can tell that's related to it running in an iphone context. Try iPad landscape and it should go away.

Comment: In order to get to the RootViewController, I have created a class for the split view controller with the name `GlobalSplitViewController`, assigned it in Main.storyboard and then I added this code to the newly created class.

[link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2c690f85d4387db2fa869c06e325ce8)

Comment: title in not showing in nav bar in Detail and RootController. I tried `self.navigationItem.titleView =  CustomNavBar.center(title: "Reschedule")`. I also tried `self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView =  CustomNavBar.center(title: "Bookings")`. The order of the controllers is: 1.RevealViewController + segue to 2. NavController + segue to 3. Controller holding all buttons + from one button to 4. ViewController with container view + segue to 5. SplitViewController + segue both from SplitViewController and RootController to 6. NavController + segue to DetailVC.

Answer (score 0):

> Pushing a split view controller through navigation controller is not
>   possible, but there is a alternative that get the job done

You can create a view controller and add the split view controller as a child and then you can push that created view controller through the navigation controller. It will show your split view controller and you can work with both master and detail. add the navigation push method to didselect method in tableview

***remember** to add the yoursplitviewcontroller class to custom class in storyboard

***note*** splitcontroller -> (master, detail)

```
let splitVC = getViewController(storyBoardName: "story board name", viewControllerName: "split view controller identifier") as! yoursplitviewcontroller
        view.addSubview(splitVC.view)
        view.bounds = splitVC.view.bounds
        addChild(splitVC)

func getViewController(storyBoardName: String, viewControllerName: String) -> UIViewController{
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyBoardName, bundle: nil)
        return storyBoard.instantiateViewController(identifier: viewControllerName)
    }
```